# pass parameter to onClick function of leaflet easybutton

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i am working with leaflet easybutton, when i create some button by forloop and i want pass the id of clicked button to onClick function

```
var Filetime = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
  for (i = 0; i < Filetime.length; i++) {
    var mybutton = L.easyButton({
      id:String(Filetime[i]),
      states:[{
        icon:'<strong>'+String(Filetime[i])+'</strong>',
        onClick: function(e){
          alert(id)
        }]
    })
```

i expect output is id of my button but i have an error id is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not defined indeed. the followings may be helpful:

```
var Filetime = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
for (var i = 0; i < Filetime.length; i++) {
    (function () {
        var id = String(Filetime[i])
        L.easyButton({
            id: id,
            states: [
                {
                    icon: '<strong>' + id + '</strong>',
                    onClick: function (e) {
                        alert(id);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: it's can't create a button

Comment: @vmphuong it's a pleasure, so could you accept this as the best answer?